# How to prevent 'automatically sort object property in alphabetical order' in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, object

I'm initializing an object in angular with un-ordered key defined but when I print it on html it automatically changes to alphabetically.

I've tried to resolve using `tslint.json` to set some rules like as follows

```
{
    "extends": ["tslint:recommended"],
    "rules": {
        "object-literal-sort-keys": false 
    }
}
```

as well as

```
"jsRules":{
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
}
```

but nothing effect on expected output.

initialize object in `App.component.ts`

```
abc: Object = {'State': 'asd', '1': 'roshan', '2': 'ramanuj', 'city': 252};
```

app.component.html

```
<div>{{ abc | json }}</div>
```

I expect the output is `{"State": "asd", "1": "roshan", "2": "ramanuj", "city": 252 }` but actual output is `{ "1": "roshan", "2": "ramanuj", "State": "asd", "city": 252 }`

Comment: Note that tslint has nothing to do with the runtime behavior, it's just a set of rules that your editor (like vscode) uses to give you errors/warnings when coding.

Comment: yes i know this but i try it because i assume to may be it can effect on compile time changes and get output but it not effect.
But this ordering where perform i can't detect

Comment: Ok, but tslint has no effect on the compiler either. It's simply to give the coder feedback while coding.

Comment: i understand it destination of Coding standards for pacific language like ES, TS, JS and etc, Editors can use for document formatting

Answer (score 0):

You should define an array here

`abc = [ {name: 'Ramesh'}, { name: 'asd'} , {name: 'avinash'}, {name: 252} ];`

Use `ngFor` to print it

`<div *ngFor="let item of abc">{{item.name}}</div>`

Comment: i think your not understand my problem, issue is not name issue **why key was auto sorting in printing not same as initialize**

Comment: In JS object, the key are enumerated when traversed and it is automatically ordered by JS. In your case, the keys are both numbers and strings. You need a better data-structure if you need to overcome your issue. You should use array here. For reference, you can take a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-keys-javascript/)